# Should I take consent before listing referee names?

Tags: mathematics, peer-review, paper-submission

I am about to submit my research article in a Mathematics journal and the online system is asking to mention three Referee/Reviewer names.

Should I take the consent of a few experts in my topic before I enlist three expert names as referees, by individually mailing them?

I think, I should take.

Any suggestions and advice regarding the question, please?

Comment: Any reason for downvote. At least leave some comment please so that I can correct the question

Comment: It's not just unnecessary to ask them, it's inappropriate - it would be a violation of the blind review process. Journals ask for referee suggestions to make life easier for the associate editors to find referees. They figure you might know the people in your sub-field better than they do. There's an ethical obligation on you to suggest people you think will give your paper a good and fair review, not your close friends/collaborators (that would also be inappropriate).

Comment: @StuartGolodetz, It is inappropriate, I agree. But how is it violation ? Even if I take consent of experts and list them in referee list, it doesn't mean Editor will choose them just like Editor may not choose the list of referee which I put randomly without taking consent from experts. The outcome of both way is same.

Comment: I think you can remove the question in the edit---it is not unfair.  Also, in mathematics I have never known a journal to require suggesting referees, so unless it is stated otherwise, you can safely ignore this question.  (I always do.)

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR It's a potential violation of blind review in the sense that if the reviews are supposed to be double-blind (as they are in some cases), then the reviewers shouldn't know the identities of the authors, and if you contact potential reviewers in advance and they're later chosen by the editor, they will. Suggesting potential reviewers to the editor without contacting them doesn't violate blind review - my original point was merely that contacting them individually could.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz, ok,  but the journal,  I am talking,  has single-blind review policy. The referee will always know the identity of authors'. In that, I don't think it is violation

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Before proposing reviewers, should I notify them?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/74898/7734)

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR I did not downvote, but keep in mind that it is perfectly acceptable to downvote without comments on SE. You may *politely* invite downvoters to leave a comment to improve your question, but your comment "at least leave a comment" sounds like you are *expecting* it, and I find this request quite rude. Please try to use kinder words in future.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, yes. But I said, give some reason if someone downvote so that the OP can correct the question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft,  Thanks for noticing this. However I didn't find before

Comment: I have submitted to Elsevier journals many times (though not J Alg) and never suggested referees.  You can skip this unless it explicitly says this is mandatory.  What is sometimes required (and sometimes optional, and sometimes not even asked for) is recommending an editor to handle your submission.

Comment: @Kimball, No it wasn't mandatory. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No. You do not need consent from them. There is no convention to do that.

Usually, the whole peer review process is an anonymous one, with the selection of reviewers occuring at the editors' full discretion. The editors have various channels to find suitable reviewers, and they usually do not tell the reviewers (nor the authors) how they came across them.

Answer (score 17):

As an author, you should never ask someone's permission before suggesting them as a reviewer.  This prevents a situation where a reviewer thinks you are offering a bribe.  While this is unlikely, you should not leave any room for confusion.

There might be rare exceptions where you are required to ask for permission; I encountered this once and it was a waste of time.

Comment: The advice is correct, but I don't see how it could be seen as a bribe. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Buffy The reviewer recommends acceptance of your paper, then asks you to review (and expects you to recommend) his/her paper in return. In some cultures, nobody does *anything* "for free" - you always expect to get something in return.

Comment: @Buffy I didn't say it could be seen as a bribe, because it is not.  I said it could be *mistaken* for an *offer* of a bribe.  Any direct author/reviewer interaction could lead to this mistake.

Answer (score 13):

It's not necessary. Firstly the editor might not use your suggested referees; secondly, if they do invite them then they will be writing to them themselves, so you writing to them first does nothing. After all, if they agree to referee your paper in response to your email, they would still have to agree to referee your paper when the editor invites them.

Answer (score 0):

As others wrote, you don't have an obligation to ask the potential referees for permission to suggest them to the journal. However, I don't think asking for permission is problematic. I asked some people for permission. Some of them agreed, some of them refused, saying my work is beyond their area of expertise or interest or that they did not agree with my work. I just don't see any problem with that. For example, I don't think referees' permission prevents them from refusing to referee the article if the editor asks them to.